# Can parse one document, but not another

Tags: php, xml, formatting, cdata

I have two XML documents, both formatted like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<article>
  <body>
    <![CDATA[
      *some text*
    ]]>
  </body>
</article>
```

and I want to echo them using this:

```php
<?php
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("." . $filename); 
  echo $xml->body;
?>
```

But one of them works, the other just echos nothing. What is going on?

UPDATE:
The document which produces the error contains this appostrophe: '
When this apostrophe is removed, the code works. I need some way of escaping characters like this, how can I do it?

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the output?

Comment: I think simpleXML already does that. Anyway, it works with one XML, so why shouldn't it work with the other?

Answer (score 0):

Just echo `asXML()` you may see your error with the second file.

```php
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Here is a simple tutorial on SimpleXML: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: The article which this didn't work for didn't echo anything back

Answer (score 0):

Espace your appostrophe:

```
<?php
  $text = file_get_contents("." . $filename); 
  $text = str_replace("'", "&apos;", $text);
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($text); 
  echo $xml->body;
?>
```

Also, someone had a similar problem (no crash but garbage characters) and came up with the same solution. A bit later in that forum thread they speculate on utf8_encode and utf8_decode, which you could also try. Link: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10359181-RESOLVED-SimpleXML-apostrophe-problem&p=10886946&viewfull=1#post10886946

Comment: that's great, but what if there are other characters which can cause this problem?

Comment: try utf8_decode() instead of str_replace(), it could be the issue.